# Should an NSString property under ARC be strong or copy?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, declared-property

When not compiling with ARC, it is recommended to use `copy` properties for data types such as `NSString`. I could not find proper documentation on the use of `copy` in ARC mode. Can someone tell me what's applicable for ARC?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show an example piece of code where you want to know the proper method to follow.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It is still recommended to copy because you want to avoid something passing a mutable string and then changing it without you knowing. A copy guarantees that the string you have will not change.

Comment: Note that when I say "guarantee" I am referring to code that conforms to Objective-C best practices. I can't account for a rogue programmer who thinks it is smart to add `copy` method to an `NSString` category for example.

Comment: what about `NSMutableArray` should I use copy for it.

Comment: If you have an `NSMutableArray` that you want to be modified outside of your class then no, otherwise return a `mutableCopy` they can modify independently of your class.

Answer (score 14):

Copying and ARC are orthogonal: you make copies of mutable objects to "freeze" their state; ARC keeps track of object's reference count.

`NSString` objects may or may not be mutable. When you receive an `NSString*` as a parameter, you cannot be certain that it is immutable unless you check its type (and even then you may get false positives). If your algorithm relies on the string not changing after being set, making a copy is the right thing to do. ARC, on the other hand, will ensure that the object is not released while you are holding a strong reference to it.

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't matter if you're using **ARC** or **non-ARC**.

The reasoning behind the `copy` is so that you can guarantee that your class' internal state can't be modified from outside the implementation.

This could happen if someone passes you an `NSMutableString`, and then modifies it later. That consideration is independent of the memory management environment.

Answer (score 11):

`copy` counts as `strong`. Use:

> @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;

https://devforums.apple.com/message/654033#654033

or even:

> @property NSString *firstName;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW7

Comment: The first link is not accessible for me, can someone quote the exact post in the link?